# How to visualize values stored in a 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, 3d, data-visualization

I have an array of floating point values ranging from 0.0 to 70000.0 and I want to visualize this data in a 3D surface. I want something like this:
[image]

I have no idea how to do this. I don't even know what this type of graph is actually called. Should I use Matlab? I haven't used Matlab before but I have access to a machine which has Matlab installed on it...

Comment: No answer!!! Come on guys I really need this. Please anyone at least tell me what is it called (I mean what kind of graph) so that I can figure the rest of the stuff googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools like [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) can produce a very similar plot.

The figure you provide displays the matrix as a height-map. For a matrix `M` with elements `M[i][j]`, the 3D surface you want is simply:

```
x = i
y = j
z = M[i][j]
```

The surface is visualized with a rendering algorithm like [ray marching](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/terrainmarching/terrainmarching.htm) or [rasterizing](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/beautiful_landscapes_by_means_of_height_mapping/16006/) a mesh overlaid with the height map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @a.lasram. I'm going to look into it.